# Filter USB Power noise after Voltage Regulator?

Tags: power, usb, noise, layout

I have designed a product which will be powered from USB `5V` power supply. My product has two PCB. One PCB has USB connector, `FTDI FT234XD`, Voltage regulator (`LM11173V3`) and few passive components (`Ferrite bead`, `capacitors` and `resistors`). This circuit connects to other PCB which has sensitive analog sensor and `PIC24E`. After doing some experiments, I found out if I use my first PCB (PCB with usb) alone and check `3.3V` output of Voltage regulator with a Digital Oscilloscope, then it has `92mV` `Peak-to-Peak` noise. I want to reduce that noise and noise frequency.

The screenshot of oscillator is (without ferrite bead):
[image]

The schematic of PCB with USB connector is:
[image]

I have observed that if I solder ferrite bead (`BLM18AG121SN1`), then peak-to-peak noise increases to 200mV.

The layout of USB PCB is:

[image]

My questions are:

1. Can I reduce noise further?
2. How can ferrite bead in my circuit increase the noise?

**EDIT:**
My PCB has two layers with solid copper pour on both layers.

Comment: It is not clear from your layout how the ground is connected. How many layers is in your PCB? Is there a ground plane?

Comment: I have edited my question to answer you questions.

Comment: How did you probe the regulator? Did you use the ground clip?

Comment: At regulator output.

Comment: You need to show your copper pour. Also, the "noise" can be spurious due to improper ground connection of your scope leads. As Mike asks, where was your ground lead connected? How long it is?